# Similar Python tools like swift playground, simply draw values as graph

Tags: python

[image]

The above is a screen shot of Swift playground. It simply displays value as graph just as one click.

Are there similar tools (plugins to IDE etc.) for python? Due to python popular in data analytics projects, that would be helpful if we can find same tools with python IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python has [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/). This obviously requires exponentially more effort than Swift Playground, but it is the closest thing.